# Bypass first line of each file in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I am processing an S3 folder containing csv.gz files in Spark. Each csv.gz file has a header that contains column names.

The way I load the contained data to Spark is to reference the path / folder, like this:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://.../my-s3-path")
```

How can I skip the header in each file, so that I can process the values only?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("s3://.../my-s3-path").mapPartitions(_.drop(1))
```

Because each input file is gzipped, it will be loaded under a separate partition. If we map across all partitions and drop the first line, we will consequently be removing the first line from each file.