# pyspark remove header from multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark to do some data processing.

My input files and folders are in the below format:

```
Folder1/stage/file1
Folder1/stage/file2
```

Each file has the first row as a Header record and the second row as a blank line.
I am trying to remove the first 2 lines. I was able to achieve this if I have only one file in the folder by using the below command.

```
linesRCP = sc.textFile("Folder1/stage/")
noHeaderRDD = linesRCP.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (row,index): index > 1).keys()
```

But my use case is that I will have multiple files in the folder. How do I remove the first 2 rows (Header + Blank Line) from each file using pyspark.

One thing I tried is to first filter out all the blank lines which was successful but I still have not figured out a way to remove the header row from each file.

```
# This removes blank lines from all the files
rddBlank = linesRCP.filter(lambda x: x != '')
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Unfortunately, if your files are splittable, there's no guarantee that your partitions will exactly correspond to the files (meaning that files can be split across partitions). This means that your header lines may be found in the middle of partitions. How big are your files? If they are small enough, one possibility is to use the `wholeTextFiles()` loader and parse out the first two lines.

Comment: Can you show us example data with header? Do you have the same header for each file?

Comment: Yes the header is the same for each file. Also, the files are gz which means they are splittable. The beginning of the header is similar to this. Date\tTime\tType\tServ\tDuration\t

Comment: The individual files are relatively small approx. 150 KB each. But I have millions of such files.

Comment: If the input files are gzipped, they are _not_ splittable and you can use the solution described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561936/bypass-first-line-of-each-file-in-spark-scala/33562044#33562044) replacing the `drop(1)` with `drop(2)`.

Comment: Thanks for this! How is this possible using python ?